# What is the aspnet50 target framework, and can I reference it from VS2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, asp.net-core

The packages at https://www.myget.org/gallery/aspnetrelease target *aspnet50*, and when I try to install them I get:

> You are trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not  contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to manually download the nuget packages and had no problem referencing from VS 2013.

Comment: That's pretty wrong :). We made a new platform to make it incompatible with existing .NET 4.5.x projects. It'll likely "work" until it doesn't and you'll get an obscure failure

Comment: @dfowler All I need to do is compile.

Comment: I don't think that changes anything I said.

Comment: @dfowler I know. This question is more about VS and NuGet than ASP.NET. I don't need to run anything, just start working on code that I'll run when I get VS14.

Comment: It's not really. When you use a package with aspnet50 and it ends up not working at runtime in a vanilla .NET application, then we'll have this conversation again.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that (currently). If you insist on working with ASP.NET vNext in VS2013, you can use it as an editor and run everything from the commandline with the tools [from the aspnet Home repository.](https://github.com/aspnet/Home)

You should install the newest CTP of VS14 if you want to work with asp.net vNext, which you can [download the newest version of from here](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-14-ctp-vs.aspx) and learn [how to use it in this guide](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/getting-started-with-aspnet-vnext-and-visual-studio). ASP.NET vNext is in alpha currently, so documentation and information can be a bit sparse. aspnet50 is the (current) name for the new .Net framework introduced with ASP.NET vNext.